# How to make Snakemake wildcard work for empty string?

Tags: python, wildcard, bioinformatics, snakemake

I expected Snakemake to allow wildcards to be empty strings, alas, this isn't the case.

How can I make a wildcard accept an empty string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcards by default only match the regex `.+` meaning everything but empty strings. This is unfortunately [not documented](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#snakefiles-wildcards) beyond a [Google group conversation](https://groups.google.com/g/snakemake/c/S7fTL4jAYIM).

To make a wildcard accept empty strings, simply add a custom wildcard constraint `wildcard_constraints: foo=".*"`, either within the scope of a rule or globally:

```
# Option 1
wildcard_constraints:
    foo=".*"

rule a:
    input: in{foo}.txt
    output: out{foo}.txt
    wildcard_constraints: foo=".*"  # Option 2
    shell: "cp {input} {output}"
```